# Movie from the 70s or 80s that had a civilization that banned technology

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a sci-fi movie as a kid in the 80s on cable TV. It focused on a group of travelers from Earth, I believe going to another planet, that came across a civilization that banned technology. They did this because it replaced the need for humans. Does anyone know what movie this was?

Comment: Could it have been a Star Trek episode? I don't recall one exactly like that, but it sounds the kind of situation that Captain Kirk and Co might run into.

Comment: You need Technology to ban technology effectively

Comment: @Neo Darwin: Sometimes a large, ignorant mob can do the job.

Answer (score 2):

A partial match would be *[Hard to Be a God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_to_Be_a_God)*, as per my answer to  [80s movie where people go to another planet where civilization is still in the middle ages](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172944/80s-movie-where-people-go-to-another-planet-where-civilization-is-still-in-the-m/172949#172949).

> A group of 30 scientists travel from Earth to a nearly-identical alien planet that is culturally and technologically centuries behind. The inhabitants of this planet have brutally suppressed a renaissance movement, murdering anybody they consider to be an intellectual, and thus the planet is stuck in the middle ages. Anton, one of the scientists from Earth, is sent to infiltrate the local populace of the Kingdom of Arkanar and help them progress as a society, although he is forbidden from getting involved with local politics or forcibly interfering with the advancement of technology or culture. He assumes the identity of Don Rumata, a nobleman who resides in a large castle surrounded by poverty. There, he lives with Ari, a young woman whom he has taken as his bride, and the juvenile prince of Arkanar. Rumata's presence divides local opinion; some treat him as a God, others despise him.

However, I can't see any indication that technology was banned because it replaced humans.